# How do I apply Law of Iterated Expectation to this equation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ be two independent random variables and $\theta = (\theta_i, \theta_j)$. I want to apply LIE to this following expression

$$E_\theta [\theta_i E_{\theta_j}f(\theta) - \theta_jE_{\theta_i}f(
\theta)] $$
and show that it is equivalent to

$$E_\theta[(\theta_i - \theta_j) f(\theta)]$$

My attempt:
$$E_\theta [\theta_i E_{\theta_j}f(\theta) - \theta_jE_{\theta_i}f(
\theta)] = E_\theta [\theta_i E_{\theta_j}f(\theta)] - E_\theta [\theta_j E_{\theta_i}f(\theta)] =  E_{\theta}[E_{\theta_i}(\theta_i E_{\theta_j}f(\theta))|\theta_i] -   E_{\theta}[E_{\theta_j}(\theta_jE_{\theta_i}f(\theta))|\theta_j] = E_\theta [\theta_i f(\theta)] - E_\theta[\theta_jf(\theta)] $$

but is the third equality true?

Comment: There's several missing/mismatching parentheses that make it hard to understand what you're writing.

Comment: Sorry! Is this better?

Comment: What does $E_{\theta_i}$ mean? isn't $E_{\theta_i}[\cdot]$ already a shorthand for $E[\cdot \mid \theta_j]$ (i.e. hold $\theta_j$ fixed, take the expectation with respect to $\theta_i$)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$E_\theta[\theta_i E_{\theta_j} f(\theta)]
= E_\theta[E_{\theta_j}[\theta_i f(\theta)]] = E_\theta[\theta_i f(\theta)].$$
The first equality is due to $\theta_i$ being fixed in the conditional expectation $E_{\theta_j}$, so it behaves just like a scalar. The second equality is the LIE.

Similarly $E_\theta[\theta_j E_{\theta_i} f(\theta)]
= E_\theta[E_{\theta_i}[\theta_j f(\theta)]] = E_\theta[\theta_j f(\theta)].$

Comment: Thanks! Does independence factor into this?